# Using git in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-databricks

I tried to setup git using Azure DevOps.
I am following this process
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/implement-ci-cd-azure-devops/3-create-ci-cd-process

As mentioned in this link i am using the format in Git Preferences, as under `https://dev.azure.com/<myOrg>/<myProject>/_git/<myRepo>` in the Link field to link Azure DevOps and Azure Databricks to the same Azure AD tenant. Substituted the `<myProject>` and `<myrepo>` with names i have created for Azure DevOps. Repository is initialized as well.
However i keep getting error message even though i dont have any < character in the URL. Infact the URL opens fine in the browser but still unable to connect git from databricks.

```
Error while syncing Git history: Unexpected character 
('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')? at [Source: ????<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">???? ?? ????<html lang="en-US">??<head><title>?? ?? Azure DevOps Services | Sign In?? ??</title><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11;&#32;IE=10;&#32;IE=9;&#32;IE=8" />?? <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/favicon.ico"/>???? <link data-bundlelength="508967" data-bundlename="commoncss" data-highcontrast="/_static/tfs/M174_20200824.6/_cssbundles/HighContrast/vss-bundle-commoncss-vbprQZmxiRGQT6OOu7QI7gB_rewyS40Ce_ulm1Fh3rQQ=" data-includedstyles="jQueryUI-Modified;Core;Splitter;PivotView" href="/_static/tfs/M174_20200824.6/_cssbundles/Default/vss-bundle-commoncss-v18eOGnLpZpVm7mtRF63HJdB9wzrq2LZpAxko9qNRfdY=" rel="stylesheet" />??<link data-bundlelength="116298" data-bundlename="viewcss" data-highcontrast="/_static/tfs/M174_2
```

Comment: The error message shows a Sign-in page. It looks like Databricks isn't passing credentials. Try generating a personal access token with the permissions to read repositories and use: `https://<myorg>:<personalaccesstoken>@dev.azure.com/<myOrg>/<myProject>/_git/<myRepo>`.

Comment: Is your Azure DevOps account backed by the same Azure Active Directory as your Azure subscription? In that cause auth should flow automatically. It it isn't, treat is as just another remote repo.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, the format of URL is
`http://dev.azure.com/<myOrg>/<myProject>/_git/<myRepo>`, you should replace the `<myOrg>` `<myProject>` `<myRepo>`. If you are not sure about the `<myOrg>` `<myProject>` `<myRepo>`, go to the repo page in Azure DevOps, and click **Clone** as the screenshot below shows:

[image]

The format of HTTPS URL is `https://<myOrg>@dev.azure.com/<myOrg>/<myProject>/_git/<myRepo>`, you can capture the `<myOrg>` `<myProject>` `<myRepo>` from this URL.

If your Azure DevOps organization is `org.visualstudio.com`, open `dev.azure.com` in your browser and navigate to your repository. Copy the URL from the browser and paste that URL in the Link field.

Comment: hi Cece, can you answer this question? thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64546693/azure-devops-running-two-builds-sequentially

Comment: @alansmith4785 Please check Kevin Lu-MSFT's reply in that case, you need to disable  CI trigger `trigger: none`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#disabling-the-ci-trigger.